# Can you propose any hack for remembering the following trigonometric formulas?

Tags: trigonometry

Can you propose any hack for remembering the following trigonometric formulas?

[image]

Comment: All the relations that don't involve $\sin$ and $\cos$ can be derived from the identities that do include $\sin$ and $\cos$. Some of these identities are applications of other identities such as $\cos(2\theta) =2\cos ^2\theta -sin^2\theta$ is just the previous double angle identity and the pythagorean identity combined.

Comment: To add, every relation here can be efficiently derived from Euler's formula $e^{i\theta}=cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$, using the properties of the exponential function $e^x$. I myself don't have many of these formulas completely memorized; I simply know what they should approximately look like, and have developed an intuition for when they are useful, so I can quickly re-derive and apply them when it makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May I share the feeling that the asked question lives on a strongly taste-dependent level?
May the further reply or essay be helpful!

You might get closer to one hack when observing that the captioned formulae blocks are related rather closely to each other, to be detailed below. In particular, the Double angle identities directly follow from the Sum/Difference identities.
$\qquad$ *Thus, memorising them all and separately appears to be not a good strategy.*
It will probably take a similar amount of time to check that the needed formula you have memorised is correct when compared to directly deriving it. I'd propose the basic starting line for the latter {sh,c}ould be the Pythagorean and Sum identities regarding sine and cosine.

> The central character to all of these is complex but not complicated, it is the exponential function.
> [image: exp]
>
> <sup>screen-shotted from
> **Prologue - The Exponential Function 
> in "Real and Complex Analysis" by Walter Rudin**</sup>

Euler's identity reads $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta +i\sin\theta$. It is often used, under the assumption $\theta\in\mathbb R$, to define the functions sine and cosine. The definitions
$$\cos z\,=\,\frac12 \big(e^{iz} +e^{-iz}\big) \;\quad\text{and}\;\quad
\sin z\,=\,\frac1{2i}\big(e^{iz} -e^{-iz}\big)$$
extend cosine and sine to the whole complex plane $\mathbb C$. It follows that
$$e^{iz}=\cos z +i\sin z\quad\forall\, z\in\mathbb C$$
holds in general, though on the RHS you loose the definite separation into real and imaginary parts.
The *Pythagorean identity* is a direct consequence since
$$1\,=\, e^0\,=\, e^{-iz}\,e^{iz}\,=\, (\cos z -i\sin z)(\cos z +i\sin z)
\,=\, \cos^2 z +\sin^2 z\quad\forall\, z\in\mathbb C\,,$$
and the two following identities on the Cheat sheet in the OP involving secans $\sec=\frac1\cos$ and cosecans $\csc=\frac1\sin$ are merely reformulations.

The *Sum/Difference identities* for sine and cosine follow from the ansatz
$$\begin{align*}
\cos(u+v) +i\sin(u+v) & \:=\: e^{i(u+v)} \:=\:  e^{iu}\, e^{iv}
 \:=\: (\cos u\,+\, i\sin u)(\cos v\,+\, i\sin v) \\[1ex]
& \:= \: \cos u\,\cos v - \sin u\,\sin v \tag{3} \\[1ex]
& \qquad +\, i\,(\cos u\,\sin v +\sin u\,\cos v)
\end{align*}$$
with $u,v\in\mathbb R$, thus allowing to separate and equate the real and imaginary parts.
Note that these identities remain valid for complex arguments, like Euler's identity.

We are at the proposed starting line:

---

Using $(3)$, the tangent's Sum/Difference identity is
$$\tan(u\pm v)\:=\:
\frac{\sin u\,\cos v\,\pm\,\cos u\,\sin v}{\cos u\,\cos v\,\mp\,\sin u\,\sin v}
\:=\:\frac{\tan u\,\pm\,\tan v}{1\,\mp\,\tan u\:\tan v}$$
where cancellation by $\,\cos u\cdot\cos v\,$ was applied. Analogously for the cotangent
$$\cot(u\pm v)\:=\:
\frac{\cos u\,\cos v\,\mp\,\sin u\,\sin v}{\sin u\,\cos v\,\pm\,\cos u\,\sin v}
\:=\:\frac{\cot u\:\cot v\,\mp\, 1}{\cot v\,\pm\,\cot u}\,.$$

The *Double angle identities* are special cases of the Sum/Difference identities, and the given listing contains some redundancy (which to cover would require allocating further memory).
Switching the arguments from $\,\theta, 2\theta\,$ to
$\,\frac\theta 2, \theta\,$ and reorganising the formulae yields all the *Half angle identities*.

Another special cases of the Sum/Difference identities are the *Cofunction identities*. They arise after choosing $u=\frac\pi 2$ and $v=-\theta$ in $(3)$. Or directly in the exponential spirit you have
$$\cos\left(\frac\pi 2 -\theta\right) +i\,\sin\left(\frac\pi 2 -\theta\right)= e^{i\left(\frac\pi 2 -\theta\right)}
= e^{i\frac\pi 2}\, e^{-i\theta}
= i\big(\cos (-\theta)+ i\sin (-\theta)\big)
=\sin \theta +i\cos \theta$$

The *Product to Sum identities*, look at their RHS's, are immediate from the Sum/Difference identities.

Finally, the *Sum to Product identities* and the *Product to Sum identities* are just two faces of one medal because the variables change $\,u=\frac{x+y}2,\,v=\frac{x-y}2\,$, thus $\,x=u+v,\,y=u-v\,$ in the opposite direction, and placing the factor $\,2\,$ as desired converts one formulae block in the other one, and vice-versa.