Where do the compound angle formulae for sine and cosine come from?
$$\mathrm{cos}(\theta + \phi) = \mathrm{cos}(\theta)\mathrm{cos}(\phi) - \mathrm{sin}(\theta) \mathrm{sin}(\phi)$$
$$\mathrm{sin}(\theta + \phi) = \mathrm{cos}(\theta)\mathrm{sin}(\phi) + \mathrm{sin}(\theta) \mathrm{cos}(\phi)$$
Where do these equations come from?
I'd be interested in seeing proofs that hold for $\bf{any}$ $\theta, \phi$.
I have only seen geometric proofs that prove the above only for $\theta , \phi \in [0,\pi/2]$.
I guess it could be done using Euler's formula, but then you'd also have to prove that $e^{z+w} = e^ze^w$ for any $z,w \in \Bbb{C}$. Or maybe it follows from the McLaurin series for sine and cosine, but I'd have no idea how to work with them to prove the above.

How are you defining sine and cosine? Depending on how you define them different proofs would be more natural.

To show $e^{z+w}=e^z+e^w$, you might find this answer helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4640695/1089874

Two remarks: (1) The Sum of angles identities you are considering even hold for every $\theta, \phi\in\mathbb C$. (2) $e^{w+z} = e^we^z,\forall w,z\in\mathbb C,$ is the fundamental property of the exponential function.
For both you may look at
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4693532/316749

Very slick: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349435/proofs-of-cosxy-cos-x-cos-y-sin-x-sin-y/2996646#2996646

You could prove this algebraically by vector algebra.
Assume there exist two vectors $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which make angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ with the positive $x$-axis, such that $\theta>\phi$. Their components would be $|\vec u|\cos\theta$, $|\vec v|\cos\phi$ (along the $x$-axis) and $|\vec u|\sin\theta$, $|\vec v|\sin\phi$ (along the $y$-axis). We know they would make an angle $\theta-\phi$ with each-other. Now, if we take their dot product,
$$\vec u \cdot \vec v=|\vec u||\vec v|\cos (\theta-\phi)$$
$$\vec u \cdot \vec v=(|\vec u|\cos\theta\times|\vec v|\cos\phi)+(|\vec u|\sin\theta\times|\vec v|\sin\phi)$$
Equating both equations for the dot product,
$$|\vec u||\vec v|\cos\theta\cos\phi+|\vec u||\vec v|\sin\theta\sin\phi=|\vec u||\vec v|\cos (\theta-\phi)$$
Dividing both sides by $|\vec u||\vec v|$,
$$\cos\theta\cos\phi+\sin\theta\sin\phi=\cos (\theta-\phi)$$
If the vectors were on opposite sides of the $x$-axis, their angle would be $\theta+\phi$ and the $y$-component of the vector below the $x$-axis would be negative.
With this information, on conducting the same steps as we did before, we obtain:
$$\cos\theta\cos\phi-\sin\theta\sin\phi=\cos (\theta+\phi)$$
Now, if we took the cross product of the initial vectors $|\vec u|$ and $|\vec v|$ instead,
$$\vec u \times \vec v=\begin{bmatrix}
    \hat i & \hat j & \hat k \\
    |\vec u|\cos\theta & |\vec u|\sin\theta & 0\\
    |\vec v|\cos\phi & |\vec v|\sin\phi & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}=|\vec u||\vec v|\cos\theta\sin\phi-|\vec u||\vec v|\sin\theta\cos\phi$$
$$|\vec u \times \vec v|=|\vec u||\vec v|\sin (\theta-\phi)$$
Remember how we said $\theta>\phi$? This indicates that the cross product will produce a vector pointing into the plane; as proven by the Right Hand Screw Rule. Hence we multiply this magnitude by $(-1)$ as it points in the negative $z$-direction.
$$|\vec u \times \vec v|=-|\vec u||\vec v|\sin (\theta-\phi)$$
Equating this with the equation we derived from the cross-matrix,
$$|\vec u||\vec v|\cos\theta\sin\phi-|\vec u||\vec v|\sin\theta\cos\phi=-|\vec u||\vec v|\sin (\theta-\phi)$$
Dividing both sides by $-|\vec u||\vec v|$,
$$\sin\theta\cos\phi-\cos\theta\sin\phi=\sin (\theta-\phi)$$
If the vectors were on opposite sides of the $x$-axis, their angle would be $\theta+\phi$ and the $y$-component of the vector below the $x$-axis would be negative.
With this information, on conducting the same steps as we did before, we obtain:
$$\sin\theta\cos\phi+\cos\theta\sin\phi=\sin (\theta+\phi)$$
And there, we proved all four equations using vector algebra:
$$\sin\theta\cos\phi+\cos\theta\sin\phi=\sin (\theta+\phi)$$
$$\sin\theta\cos\phi-\cos\theta\sin\phi=\sin (\theta-\phi)$$
$$\cos\theta\cos\phi-\sin\theta\sin\phi=\cos (\theta+\phi)$$
$$\cos\theta\cos\phi+\sin\theta\sin\phi=\cos (\theta-\phi)$$
